# Google Prediction API always returns a score of 1.0 or 0.0

Tags: google-api-ruby-client, google-prediction

I'm using the the insert function of the google-api-ruby-client and passing in an array of trainingInstances.

When I call predict I used to get scores like 0.653264 and 0.346736 (using two output categories).

After doing some refactoring I now always get scores of 1.0 and 0.0 and no probabilities in between.

The prediction accuracy (measured by me) is still close to the accuracy given by the status function so it looks like the trained model is working. I just want to know why I'm not getting scores in between 1 and 0 as I would like to use those in my application.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Here is a sample of the training data I'm using:

```
"Completed Registration",32.54,2,0,1,12
"Completed Registration",27.05,2,0,1,7
"Completed Registration",27.29,1,0,3,7
"Completed Registration",24.15,1,0,1,6
"Completed Registration",26.36,2,0,1,6
"Completed Registration",27.0,3,1,3,5
"Completed Registration",22.15,3,1,3,5
"Completed Registration",27.9,2,1,1,1
"Completed Registration",21.21,2,0,3,0
"Completed Registration",24.36,3,0,3,0
"Completed Registration",53.52,2,1,3,0
"Completed Registration",24.15,8,0,3,-6
"Cancelled Registration",,2,0,3,76
"Cancelled Registration",,2,0,3,76
"Cancelled Registration",,3,1,3,69
"Cancelled Registration",38.27,5,0,1,63
"Cancelled Registration",37.25,2,0,3,50
"Cancelled Registration",35.59,5,1,3,49
"Cancelled Registration",19.52,2,0,3,30
"Cancelled Registration",26.7,2,0,3,28
```

I've run tests on the Google API explorer and uploaded the training data in a CSV file.

The data I first uploaded (a few weeks ago) results in a range of scores. But the exact same data uploaded today results in scores of only 1 or 0.

Could this be a character encoding problem?

Answer (score 0):

In case other people have the same question I'm posting an answer here. It turns out that internally the API can use different classifiers depending on the training data. It looks like the difference was caused by a change to the API and not by my refactoring.

Here is an explanation from someone at Google https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prediction-api-discuss/7QPhONKhZjc